# Progressively loading the racing arena in a 3D driving sim

Tags: physics, 3d-meshes, racing, car

I need advice and resources on a 3D car simulator.
I want to progressively load the track for the player as I'm thinking of porting the game to mobile devices.
This seems too difficult to me as I'm trying to separate the racing arena model design and the code as much as possible. Is there a structured method for achieving that for any model (arena/map). I think this is something that comes up a lot in games in general not just this instance.

Comment: Thats not answerable in general, except once you have a perfomance problem start optimizing it, if there is no performance problem, then go the simple road and load it completely at start

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for large maps you can separate the map into multiple chunks and load each chunk as a quad or oct tree for [LOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail) rendering. This might be a generic answer, but you will have to specify your target platform and more details if you want a more more specific answer.

[This thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/634969-choosing-an-appropriate-space-partitioning-method/?hl=%2bquadtree) might give you some ideas.